# grunt-terser Giving SyntaxError: "VARIABLE_NAME" is redeclared

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, grunt-terser

I'm using [grunt-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-terser) to minify my es6 files.
I have two files.

1. file-1.js
2. file-2.js

In both files I have required a module with same variable name like this:

```
const VARIABLE_NAME = require('MODULE_NAME');
```

Here is my grunt-terser task:

```
terser: {
      main: {
        options: { compress: true, toplevel: true },
        files: {
          './dist/app.js':
          ['file-1.js', 'file-2.js']
        }
      }
    }
```

When I run

```
npx grunt terser
```

I get the following error:

```
Running "terser:main" (terser) task
>> SyntaxError: "VARIABLE_NAME" is redeclared
```