# grunt-contrib-uglify v5.0.0 still unable to support ES6 Template Literals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

### UPDATE, Jan 09, 2012:

At first, I thought it was due to the single quotes within the template literal:

```
replyTo: `'MTN Support' <${functions.config().supportgmail.email}>`
```

But now, it's confirmed that even a normal template literal is not supported by `grunt-contrib-uglify`:

```
throw new Error(`Unknown sender email address: ${mailOptions.from.address}.`);
```

**Same Error:**

```
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: name «sender», expected: punc «,». 
Line 90 in functions/app-functions.js,functions/index.js,functions/viewer-functions.js,functions/site-functions.js
 Use --force to continue.
```

Note that even the `uglify-js` alone could not parse this. I'm also aware of the [`harmony` or `uglify-js-es6` version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-es6) on GitHub, but as this is for production deployment purpose, I dare not use it because it has not been updated since 4 years ago.

So is it confirmed that `grunt-contrib-uglify v5.0.0` is still not supporting **ES6 Template Literals**? Any other workarounds or alternative without changing the template literals to the traditional `+` string concatenation? Thanks!

---

### Original Question:

I have the following **Gruntfile.js**:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // define source files and their destinations
        uglify: {
            files: {
                src: 'functions/*.js',                  // source files mask
                dest: '../project-staging/functions/'  // destination folder
            }
        }
    });

    // load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    // register at least this one task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

When I run `grunt` at the command line, I hit this error:

```
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: string «MTN Support», expected: punc «,».
Line 44 in functions/app-functions.js,functions/index.js,functions/viewer-functions.js,functions/site-functions.js
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Below is the code that causes the error:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: functions.config().supportgmail.email,
    to: null,
    cc: null,
    bcc: null,
    // This is the line that causes the error:
    replyTo: `'MTN Support' <${functions.config().supportgmail.email}>`,
    subject: null,
    text: null,
    html: null
};
```

I have no idea what the error means as I don't have any error running my code except when I try to uglify it with Grunt. I also heard that the latest version of `grunt-contrib-uglify` already support **ES6**, so what else could it be? Below is the version of my Grunt and plugin, which I just installed today:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.0.0"
  }
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code? I don't think it make sense to change my code to the old way of string concatenation using the `+` as the template string is everywhere in my entire project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using [grunt-terser](https://github.com/adascal/grunt-terser) which utilizes [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser).

Comment: @RobC : `>> SyntaxError: "var-name" is redeclared` due to same variable declaration on different JS files. Same error reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629629/grunt-terser-giving-syntaxerror-variable-name-is-redeclared) and [GitHub](https://github.com/terser/terser/issues/794). It's ok, I'll figure out something else, thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that ^5.0.0 uglify version works well with ES6

Comment: U can confirm it works despite the fact all of us are trying to use it and it wont take simple things like type setting with ":" in function params